# I want to know that did I done the right thing by creating this method?

Tags: java

Actually I wanted to apply compareIgnoreCase first on two strings and then apply contains method to check that after applying compareIgnoreCase first, will contains method return true or not (I know there is a built-in method equalsIgnoreCase). Suppose 2 strings are equal but one is lowercase and second is uppercase str1 = "maaz" and str2 = "MAAZ"

this is what I've tried. I create this method for verification that after applying compareIgnoreCase first if compareIgnoreCase is return 0 means both Strings are equal, then the contains method that apply on 2 Strings should also return true otherwise return false.

```
if(a.compareToIgnoreCase(c) == 0)
        {
            boolean r = a.contains(c);
            r = true;
            System.out.println(r);
        }
        
        else
        {
            System.out.println("false");

        }
```

Comment: what is the reason for `r = true;` ??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: r = true  means that contains method will return false so it should return true because if two strings are equal consider ignoring the case the it should give the value true.  All i am asking is that the right method or not. I know there is a built-in method equalsIgnoringCase but I created this method so I want to know that the logic is correct or not

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I create this method for verification that after applying compareIgnoreCase first if compareIgnoreCase is return 0 means both Strings are equal ..."*

Correct.  This will return *0* when the strings are equivalent, ignoring the case.

For example, the following will return *0*.

```java
"abc".compareToIgnoreCase("ABC")
```

> *"... then the contains method that apply on 2 Strings should also return true ..."*

Incorrect, the *[contains](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence))* method is case-sensitive.
Additionally, the use of *compareToIgnoreCase* will not have made any adjustments to the values *a* and *c*.

The following will return *false*.

```java
"abc".contains("ABC")
```

You can achieve the result you're looking for by comparing the values when their cases have been changed.

You can use the *[toLowerCase](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase())*, and *[toUpperCase](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase())*, methods to change the case.

The following will return *true*.

```java
"aBc".toLowerCase().contains("AbC".toLowerCase())
```

So, you can change your code to,

```java
a.toLowerCase().contains(c.toLowerCase())
```